# Ruby: Convert String to Matrix

Tags: ruby, string, matrix

I have saved a hash with a matrix into a file, like this:

```
File.open("test.json", "w+") { |file| file.write("#{hash.to_json}") }
```

The hash contained following data:

```
{0=>Matrix[[-0.03, 1.3],[0.1,-0.45]],1=>Matrix[[-1.9,1.8,-0.6]]}
```

Now I read the saved file:

```
contents = File.read('test.json')
hashAgain = JSON.parse(contents) #Convert it to hash
```

But if I want to access a Matrix in the hash, the matrix is no longer in the matrix data format:

```
puts netTrained.values[0].class #=>String
```

My question is how to convert the "matrix" string back to the matrix data format?

Comment: How did you encode the Matrix into JSON? JSON doesn't support matrices, only numbers, strings, arrays, `true`, `false`, `null`, and dictionaries. You must have somehow encoded your Matrix into a combination of those, and you need to do the opposite during the decoding process.

Comment: @Jörg, I don't understand your comment. `require 'json'` adds the method `Matrix#to_json`. See my answer for elaboration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you defined the first matrix wrong. Different number of rows.

```
Matrix[[-0.03, 1.3, -0.6],[0.1,-0.45]]
```

gives

> ExceptionForMatrix::ErrDimensionMismatch: row size differs (2 should
>   be 3)

Matrix does not accept strings for its creation. But it accepts Arrays. So, one solution would be for you to save the array in the file instead of the Matrix strings. If you save in the file "0.1,-0.45" you can do something like:

```
Matrix["0.1, -0.45".split(',')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can do that:

```
require 'json'
require 'matrix'

m0, m1 = Matrix[[1,2],[3,4]], Matrix[[5,6],[7,8]]
  #=> [Matrix[[1, 2], [3, 4]], Matrix[[5, 6], [7, 8]]] 
h = {0=>m0, 1=>m1 }
  #=> {0=>Matrix[[1, 2], [3, 4]], 1=>Matrix[[5, 6], [7, 8]]}
js = h.to_json
  #=> "{\"0\":\"Matrix[[1, 2], [3, 4]]\",\"1\":\"Matrix[[5, 6], [7, 8]]\"}" 
File.write("temp", js)
  #=> 59
JSON.parse File.read("temp")
  #=> {"0"=>"Matrix[[1, 2], [3, 4]]", "1"=>"Matrix[[5, 6], [7, 8]]"}
```

Without `require json`, we have:

```
ObjectSpace.each_object(Module).select { |m| m.instance_methods.include?(:to_json) }
  #=> []
```

but after

```
require 'json'
```

we have:

```
to_json_modules = ObjectSpace.each_object(Module).select { |m|
  m.instance_methods.include?(:to_json) }
to_json_modules.size
  #=> 527 (Ruby v2.3.0) 
to_json_modules.include?(Matrix)
  #=> true
```